# self.title and nav bar not working in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

For some reason, when I used to just have

```
self.title = @"Title";
```

to get the title bar to show up... but now in iOS 7 it won't show anything.

I've been working on this for about 2 hours... and I can't even get the title bar up and running.

I've also tried

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Title";
self.navigationItem.title = @"Title";
```

none of the above work.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Title";
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Title";
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"Title";
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

I don't know what else to try, I just downloaded the latest version of iOS 7/Xcode and I used the tab template.

I am really new to Xcode so I don't really know what i am doing.

---

Edit, more info below:

[image: First Images]

[image: Second Images]

[image: Third Images]

[image: Fourth Images]

[image: Fifth Images]

Comment: You can see a navbar, right?

Comment: Here's a silly question. Is this view controller actually in a navigation controller?

Comment: @Undo no I don't see a navbar... that is the problem

Comment: @rmaddy I'm not sure... I just need the title to show... I don't need a back button or anything... Do I still need a navigation controller?

Comment: You say you don't see a navbar? Maybe you should change your question into something like "navbar not showing on iOS 7"? Is this view in a nav controller? Is that the root view controller of main window? Give us some more details, maybe a screenshot...

Comment: @FilipRadelic I added screenshots above.

Comment: Like @Scott answered, you are telling Interface Builder to simulate a nav bar, not actually create it. Select your view controller (click the black bar below its view) and from Xcode's Editor view choose Embed In -> Navigation Controller and change your simulated metrics to default ("Inferred").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you have done is set the "simulated metrics". That's all that does: it simulates the navigation bar. It doesn't actually give you a navigation bar. You're saying you don't need to actually navigate, so you don't need a navigation controller. Although that's a perfectly fine approach, a navigation controller comes with more perks. For example, setting `self.title` will not work with a standalone navigation bar, but a navigation controller sets its navigation bar's title to whatever `self.title` is.

So, in your case, I would simply embed your view controller in a navigation controller, even if you're not using any of the actual navigation features.

Comment: Yup, all i needed was to put a navigation controller before the view controller.

Answer (score 0):

What you can also do is declare the Navigation Item as an IBOutlet and then change the title of that outlet, like so

in .h

```
IBOutlet UINavigationItem *navItem;
```

in .m

```
navItem.title = @"New Title";
```

That works too, but make sure you link the outlets in Interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.title=@"!@#$%^&*()";
UILabel *headlinelabel = [UILabel new];
headlinelabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Light" size:28];
headlinelabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
headlinelabel.textColor = [UIColor customBlueColor];

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString =[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.title];
headlinelabel.attributedText = attributedString;
[headlinelabel sizeToFit];
[self.navigationItem setTitleView:headlinelabel];
```

You can try this ):

Answer (score 0):

try out

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"The Title";
```